# Fine tuning Windows visual aspects in Windows 8.1

Tags: fonts, desktop, fontconfig

I'm using Windows 8.1. I know that in Windows 7 I was able to adjust *all* (just about) all of the visual aspects of the window, and the desktop, such as the font in the title bar or even in desktop icons.

Am I missing something or was that something that didn't make the upgrade? Is there an easy – as in free and without a regedit hack?

Thank you.

Ross

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the desktop icons in Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Personalization then click on change desktop icons in the top left of the window.

For the fonts: Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Display with a lot of options for fonts at different locations such as the title bars, menus, etc. It also has links to other customizing options in the left sidebar.

Hope that is what you are looking for.

Comment: No, I tried those before I came to Super-User. If I want to, for example, change the font to desktop icons to Arial italic 8 point, how would I do that?

Ross

Comment: The only waty to change font is by using a registry editor. They removed the feature in windows 8. You can only edit the size of the text.

Comment: Well, that stinks! Looking at the registry key above, it looks like everything I want is there; just not as easy as I like. Inscrutable are the ways of Microsoft…

Thanks
Ross

Answer (score -1):

Well, I bit the bullet: I went to personalization and selected "high contrast white" and then choosing colors I thought appropriate for each Windows element. The resulting windows are certainly unique! :-)

But it works!